# How can i use websocket protocol in js?

Tags: java, javascript, http, websocket, tomcat7

```
ws = new MozWebSocket("ws://localhost:8080/html5WebSocket/mywebsocket.do");
```

I used the code above to execute websocket request but found that the connection was closed immediately with the method onclose called.

```
ws.onclose = function(evt) {
        alert("close");
    };
```

The net tab of firebug shows the request url from browser to tomcat is **http**://localhost:8080/html5WebSocket/mywebsocket.do.
I expected the url to be **ws**://localhost:8080/html5WebSocket/mywebsocket.do.

What have I done wrong?

Comment: This should be tagged as JavaScript, not Java, two completely different things. Retagged for you

Answer (score 2, accepted):

MozWebSocket was used in Firefox 6-10, if you're using a newer Version, use WebSocket for as constructor method.

Comment: I tested this example in firefox 14.Maybe i need to change it to firefox 10.thanks!

Answer (score 0):

It is normal to see a connection to `http://...` when using web sockets, since the web socket handshake is otherwise indistinguishable from an HTTP "upgrade" request.

The problem is likely server-side, not client-side.

Answer (score 0):

I use the "WebSocket"-class in javascript. It works in Safara, Firefox and Chrome. Here is an example:

```
var ws = new WebSocket(wsUrl);
ws.onopen = function() {
    ...
};
ws.onmessage = function(evt) {
   ...
};
ws.onclose = function() {
   ...
};
```

On serverside i work with Tomcat & Jetty-Websocket (http://wiki.eclipse.org/Jetty/Feature/WebSockets)

Comment: Why it can't works in the latest version of IE 9 and Chrome 24 according to my test?I nearly used all the approaches.